# Using Djongo (Mongo ORM) with CosmosDB?

Tags: django, mongodb, azure-cosmosdb, djongo

I am currently trying to use [djongo](https://github.com/nesdis/djongo) with a [CosmosDB](https://azure.microsoft.com/fr-fr/services/cosmos-db/) database as CosmosDB integrate the MongoDB API.

I enabled both 'Aggregation Pipeline' and '3.4 wire protocol' as Djongo require MongoDB 3.4 to work.

With this setup, i cannot pass the initial django migration. I did not have any problem with a local MongoDB instance.

Here is djongo output when running `python manage.py migrate`:

```
djongo.sql2mongo.SQLDecodeError: FAILED SQL: CREATE TABLE "django_migrations" ("id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "app" char NOT NULL, "name" char NOT NULL, "applied" datetime NOT NULL)
Pymongo error: OrderedDict([('_t', 'OKMongoResponse'), ('ok', 0), ('code', 48), ('errmsg', "a collection 'iot_data.__schema__' already exists"), ('$err', "a collection 'iot_data.__schema__' already exists")])
```

I can see in the data explorer of CosmosDB that two collections has been created: `__schema__` and `django_migrations` but `django_migrations` is empty.

I have no previous experience with no-sql so maybe I am misunderstanding something.

I don't know if anyone already try to use Djongo with a CosmosDB database but any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Are you able to resolve this issue. I am facing the same.

Comment: Did you solve the problem by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

seems you are using "embeddedmodelfields", please try using models.ForeignKey from "djongo.models". create the new database and run the migrations .